# What is the easiest way to insert Unicode characters into a document?

Tags: insert-mode, unicode, input-methods

When writing documents occasionally I want to insert Unicode characters into the text. Sometimes I know the character code and sometimes I look it up on the web.

Currently I go to insert mode and then use `<Ctrl-V>u{four digit hex number}`, which can be very laborious. Is there an easier way of inserting the characters (maybe some form of pasting)?

Comment: The other question is really a "special case" of this more generic question; the answers will be the same... My comment there also applies: Use you OS' facilities (whatever they may be), or some other OS-wide program (for examplle when I used Windows, I liked to use AllChars which emulates X11's Compose key; it works in all programs).

Comment: Yes that is a special case and the answers are specialized for it. Do you not think there may be a more generalized solution that encompases more things that people did not consider when looking at the special case.

Comment: We could also make that question more generic, or mark that one a dupe of this one (even though it was earlier); I don't really care *as such*. But I don't think that having both questions as it is will help anyone in the long term :-)

Comment: If I could control the world. Maybe we should let it stand for a day or two so if it gathered any unique responses that could distinguish it from the other question. If it remains unanswered or the answers are just duplicates then close/delete it.

Comment: All right .. I definitely agree the other question doesn't have *great* answers, and this question should attract better ones (hopefully) ... Editing the other question (to make it more generic) still leaves it with a bunch of highly upvoted answers that deal *only* with the em dash, so that's not great either ... So I've retracted my close vote, and as soon as this gets some decent answers I'll vote the other oone a dupe of this one (even though it was earlier)... I of course can't control what other people choose to vote.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: If we had a mod then they have the power to combine questions I believe which is another options. We could as a group potentially edit the questions together if that made sense in the long run.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Preface**: This has nothing to do with Vim as such, but I will show you what I consider to be the "best" way to insert these characters by far; Vim's digraph system is more or less the same, but it only works with Vim. This will work in *all* applications.

**This will only work for X11 systems** (Linux, BSD, etc.). **For Windows, there's [AllChars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/)**. It hasn't been updated in a while, but I can confirm it works well with Windows 7 (used it at my previous job). I believe OS X also has good facilities to do this built in the OS; if you use OS X, I encourage you to check them out, but as I've never really used OS X I can't point you to them.

The below is (part of) a draft weblog article I have in the pipeline. Unfortunately a truly comprehensive guide doesn't exist (yet), and the below doesn't describe *all* the features it offers (for example, some parts about dead keys are missing) and could be better written in some parts, but I think it's still "useful enough".

---

A ‘compose sequence’ is pressing the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key and then one or more characters to produce some character not found on your keyboard, for example, pressing  <kbd>Compose</kbd>, immediately followed by <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> might produce an `ä`.

By default, <kbd>Compose</kbd> isn’t bound to any key<sup>1</sup>; the Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (aka. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) is often used, but you set this to any key you want.

#### Set it using xmodmap

You can use [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xmodmap.1.xhtml)
to set this:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keysym Alt_R = Multi_key'     # Set it right Alt
$ xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = Multi_key' # Set it to Caps Lock
$ xmodmap -e 'keysym F12 = Multi_key'       # You're free to use *any* key, like F12
```

You probably want to add this to your `~/.Xmodmap` file<sup>2</sup>:

```
! Set compose key
keysym Alt_R = Multi_key
```

#### Set it using XKB

You can also set the compose key as an option to XKB with
[`setxkbmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap):

```
setxkbmap -option compose:ralt  # Right alt
setxkbmap -option compose:caps  # Caps Lock
```

To make these permanent, add the command to your X startup file, or
alternatively, you can also set it in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Keyboard0"
    Driver "kbd"
    Option "XkbOptions" "compose:ralt"
    #Option "XkbOptions" "compose:caps"
EndSection
```

Or, in a more ‘modern’ style, you can create a file
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-compose.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Set compose key"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbOptions" "compose:ralt"
EndSection
```

A list of possible values can be found in [`xkeyboard-config(7)`](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=xkeyboard-config&ampsect=7), section ‘Position of Compose key’<sup>3</sup>.

### Setting up dead keys

A dead key is chiefly used to add a accent or diacritic to a letter (such as the umlaut, accent grave, etc.), although it can be used to create any character. It works by...TODO
<kbd>'</kbd>

```
keycode 133 = dead_greek NoSymbol SuperR

http://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/xorg-using-the-us-international-altgr-intl-variant-keyboard-layout/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922007/how-to-enter-greek-alpha-under-xor
keycode 48 = dead_grave apostrophe


<dead_grave> <space>       : "`"   grave # GRAVE ACCENT
<dead_grave> <dead_grave>  : "`"   grave # GRAVE ACCENT
<dead_grave> <a>           : "À"   agrave # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
```

### Making a ~/.XCompose file

The default Compose file if `~/.XCompose` is missing is
`/usr/share/X11/locale/$LANG/Compose`. Having your own `~/.XCompose` overrides the default, but you can still include the default with:

```
include "%L"
```

Changes to any Compose file takes effect when you restart an application. You don't need to restart X.

#### Compose key

A 'compose sequence' is pressing the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key and then one or more characters to produce some character, for example:

```
<Multi_key> <quotedbl> <a> : "ä" adiaeresis
```

Means that pressing <kbd>Compose</kbd>, immediately followed by <kbd>"</kbd> and
<kbd>a</kbd> produces an `ä`.

`<Multi_key>` denotes that we're using the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key.
we then follow this by a list of one or more keys, these have to be `keysyms`, which are symbolic representations of keys used by X (See the Keysyms section).

Followed by a `:`, followed by the result.

The result:

```
<Multi_key> <a>          :  "ä" adiaeresis
<Multi_key> <b> <b>      :  "ä" adiaeresis
<Multi_key> <c> <c> <c>  :  "ä" adiaeresis
<Multi_key> Alt <d>      :  "ä" adiaeresis
<Multi_key> Ctrl <e>     :  "ä" adiaeresis
```

**Note**: A Compose file is case-sensitive, so `A` is *not* the same as `a`.

#### Dead keys

TODO

### Make it work in GTK & Qt

Set the environment variables `GTK_IM_MODULE` & `QT_IM_MODULE` to `xim`.

Bourne shell:

```
# Make compose key work for GTK, Qt
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

C shell:

```
# Make compose key work for GTK, Qt
setenv GTK_IM_MODULE xim
setenv QT_IM_MODULE xim
```

### See Also

- [Compose(5)](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.xhtml)
- [XKB](http://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/)
- [ComposeKey at edubuntu wiki](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ComposeKey)
- [ComposeKey at Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)
- [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_Configuration_in_Xorg)
- [How to make Compose work in GTK and Qt apps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/how-to-make-compose-work-in-gtk-and-qt-apps)
- [Compose key at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key)
- [Dead key at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)
- [AllChars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/) (compose key for MS Windows)
- [Enabling Compose Key in GNOME](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/tips-specialchars.html.en).

### My `~/.XCompose`

[This is the `~/.XCompose` that I use](https://bitbucket.org/Carpetsmoker/config/src/tip/modules/x11/XCompose?at=default);
I used a script to generate this, but I accidentally overwrote this when compiling it >_< So I need to rewrite it.

Also take note of this line:

```
<Multi_key> <i> <b> : "NL65AEGO0721647952"
```

Pressing <kbd>Compose ib</kbd> will insert this string (a random test IBAN number); very useful for testing applications where such a number is required to create some object (Person, Organisation); XCompose can also serve as a "snippet" tool :-)

### Footnotes

1:
Some UNIX keyboards had a dedicated <kbd>Compose</kbd> key ([like this
SUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#mediaviewer/File:Compose_key_on_Sun_Type_5c_keyboard.jpg)),
but this is fairly uncommon these days.

2:
Depending on your existing setup, this may or may not be read at startup,
depending on your config, add the line `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to either
`~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`;
[also see the ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Activating_the_custom_table).

3:
Reproduced for your benefit:

```
    Position of Compose key
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    |Option                Description                     |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    |compose:ralt          Right Alt                       |
    |compose:lwin          Left Win                        |
    |compose:lwin-altgr    3rd level of Left Win           |
    |compose:rwin          Right Win                       |
    |compose:rwin-altgr    3rd level of Right Win          |
    |compose:menu          Menu                            |
    |compose:menu-altgr    3rd level of Menu               |
    |compose:lctrl         Left Ctrl                       |
    |compose:lctrl-altgr   3rd level of Left Ctrl          |
    |compose:rctrl         Right Ctrl                      |
    |compose:rctrl-altgr   3rd level of Right Ctrl         |
    |compose:caps          Caps Lock                       |
    |compose:caps-altgr    3rd level of Caps Lock          |
    |compose:102           <Less/Greater>                  |
    |compose:102-altgr     3rd level of <Less/Greater>     |
    |compose:paus          Pause                           |
    |compose:prsc          PrtSc                           |
    |compose:sclk          Scroll Lock                     |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: For Windows, use [Wincompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose) instead of Allchars. It does exactly what it says on the tin. I used Allchars until I found Wincompose. The limitation of compose is that you can't have a memorable combination to reach all characters, only the ones that you use often or that have a logical decomposition.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks; WinCompose looks nice. You're right that you can only enter a fairly limited subset of "most used" characters. For me this is enough >95% of the time. For the rest I use [UniView](http://rishida.net/uniview/)... I'm not aware of anything significantly better...

Comment: For rarely-used characters, I use [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) (no editor integration that I know of) or I type the character name (`C-x 8 RET` in an editor that isn't vi, I don't know if Vim has something similar).

Comment: KDE users cannot use this method as [KDE relegates responsibility for implementing this feature to Xorg](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103788), and [Xorg relegates to Qt](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26747), and [Qt relegates back to Xorg](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-8). I discuss this on my page about [typing RTL text](http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html).

Comment: @dotancohen That looks like a different issue (as in, feature request).

Comment: *Make it work in GTK & Qt* I put that code into `~/.gnomerc`. Probably in could be also in `~/.xsessionrc`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, maybe you can find [this post](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) interesting. I have added a `dead-greek` key to my layout now, and `alt-g b` gives me a nice β... and using CapsLock as a compose key is really the best thing after slices bread.

Comment: [AllChars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/) works great on Windows! Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

To insert Unicode characters such as the euro or copyright symbols, or diacritical marks such as the German umlaut or accent grave, `digraphs` can be used.

For example, in insert mode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and type the following:

- Spanish: `a'` for `á`, `E'` for `É`, `n?` for `ñ`,
- German: `a:` for `ä`, `ss` for `ß`,
- other accented letters: `a!` for `à`, `a>` for `â` for `ê`, `a?` for `ã`,
- Greek: `a*` for `α` (alpha), `b*` for `β` (beta), `g*` for `γ` (gamma), `d*` for `δ` (delta).
- square numbers: `22` for `²`, `33` or `³`
- currencies: `Eu` for `€` (Euro), `Pd` for `£` (Pound),
- `Co` for `©` (Copyright), `DG` for `°` (Degree),
- `OK` for `✓`, `XX` for `✗`, `Sb` for `∙` (bullet),
- punctuation marks: `-N` for `–` (en dash), `-M` for `—` (em dash)

When the digraph option is set (`:set dg`), you can also use the following method:

- `a`<kbd>Backspace</kbd>`:` for `ä`, `E`<kbd>Backspace</kbd>`u`for `€`, etc.

To list currently defined digraphs type: `:digraphs` (`:dig`).

Source: [Entering special characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters) at the Vim [Wikia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikia) site.

---

**OS X**

If you're using OS X, it's very easy to type accented letters anywhere by the following method:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd> for `á`, <kbd>e</kbd> for `é`, <kbd>i</kbd> for `í` and similar,
- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd> for `ã`, <kbd>n</kbd> for `ñ` and similar,
- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, then <kbd>u</kbd> for `ü`,
- upside-down punctuation marks: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for `¡`, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> for `¿`,

---

See also:

- [Working with Unicode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)
- [What is the easiest way to insert en dash in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-insert-en-dash-in-vim)

Answer (score 9):

My [unicode plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) allows for easy input of unicode characters. Specifically it allows

- `:Digraph <name>` - Search digraphs for character
- `:UnicodeTable` - Displays a characterset table
- `:UnicodeName` - Identify character under cursor
- Completing of characters using their names or values from the unicode table (`:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-Z`) or the digarphs (`:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL_G`)

Read the help for more info on how to use my plugin.

Answer (score 4):

For commonly used characters, `:digraph` or external means such as the mentioned *Compose* key are great. For rarely used ones, I define abbreviations, like this:

```
norea <unique> unicode_smiley 
norea <unique> unicode_skull ☠
```

And then use my [SnippetComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2926) to get a popup menu that list all such abbreviations, e.g. : `unicode_<C-x>]`

Answer (score 3):

In adition to using the predefined digraphs (Run `:dig` to get a list), you can also define your own digraphs in vim:

```
:digr e: 235 a: 228
```

See also: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html